# Sea Ice data - MATLAB 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I want to make a matrix in which data is in a matrix and I can pull out each grid in the matrix as a certain long, lat point. The data lasts over 3 years so I would also need a 3rd dimension as time.

What I have now is three 1437x159 doubles of lat, long, and sea ice data. How do I combine them into a 3d matrix that fits the criteria I mentioned above? Basically, I want to be able to say, I want data at -50S lat and 50W lon at day 47 and be able to index into the array and find that answer.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `cat(3, lat, long, sea_ice)`?

Comment: The thing is that my sea ice data is a different matrix for each day. I need to be able to index into a specific day as well.

Comment: Then I don't understand how your data is stored. Can you visualize it somehow?

Comment: I have about 1000 hdf files that contain a variable called ASI Ice Concentration. Each file corresponds to the sea ice data on that day at each point (lat, lon) around the globe. In another part of the code, I read in the Ice concentration data from each day in a loop - so I end up with about 1000 sets of data that cover the world. I need to do what you suggested above, but also be able to specify the day I need. Basically, I'm imagining a cube in which the matrix is data across all these days. Each grid, would correspond to a certain lat, lon, say 1S and 1W. But in the grid would be data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes- this can be done without too much difficulty. I have done analogous work in analyzing atmospheric data across time.

The fundamental problem is that you have data organized by hour, with grids varying dynamically over time, and you need to analyze data over time. I would recommend one of two approaches.

**Approach 1: Grid Resampling**

This involves resampling the grid data over a uniform, standardized grid. Define the grid using the Matlab `ndgrid()` function, then resample each point using `interp2()`, and concatonate into a uniform 3D matrix. You can then directly interpolate within this resampled data using `interp3()`.  This approach involves minimal programming, with the trade-off of losing some of the original data in the resampling process.

**Approach 2: Dynamic Interpolation**

Define a custom class wrapper around your data object, say 'SeaIce', and write your own `SeaIce.interp3()` method. This method would load the grid information for each hour, perform the interpolation first in the lateral dimension, and subsequently in the time dimension. This ensures that no information is lost via interpolation, with the tradeoff of more coding involved.

The second approach is described in detail (for the wind domain) in my publication "Wind Analysis in Aviation Applications".  [Slides available here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=06383045).